# How to correctly configure CONCURRENT_REQUESTS in a project with multiple spiders

Tags: scrapy, scrapyd

I have a project in Scrapy with ~10 spiders, I run a few of them simultaneously using [Scrapyd](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd). However, I have doubts whether my `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` setting is correct.

Currently my `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS` is `32`, but I have seen that they recommend that this value be much higher (>= 100). But I have a question, is it the total number of concurrent requests that all the running spiders can make or is it the number of concurrent requests that a single spider can make?

I'm assuming it's the number of concurrent requests that all spiders can make and that's why they recommend that it be as high as possible. And I see that I can regulate the number of requests each spider will make using `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN`.

Comment: I don't have any experience with scrapyd, however I can say with certainty that the CONCUURRENT_REQUESTS option in the scrapy settings applies to each spider individually.

Comment: @Alexander Thank you for your prompt response. You are right, each spider gets the value of `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`. I will do some tests with scrapyd, and as soon as I have the results I will add the answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Scrapyd can manage multiple projects, each of which contains multiple
> spiders. CONCURRENT_REQUESTS operates per-project (i.e. for all
> spiders in that project).

Reference: [issue #463](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapyd/issues/463)